# write created data names to a file

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Hi i running selenium webdriver c# and i am trying to write certain created items to either a file or the console.

example:
Lets say i am creating a car. i generate a license plate for the car say "08test1234" now i want to write that value to some where so i can manually check it at a later time. As sometimes id like to go in and manually find the car to do some modifications.

I have tried `Console.WriteLine("08test1234");` and `Debug.Print("08test1234");` but cannot get either of these to show any where.

Any help is much appreciated.

here is one of the tests

```
   [Fact]
        [Trait("2.", "Participants Tests")]
        public void _2_Cancel_Create_Participant()
        {
            Utilities.CorrectLogin(_driver, Utilities.ManageWorkshopsURL);

            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Utilities.CreateParticipantURL);
            Utilities.WaitforElement(_driver, "uiCreateParticipantFormCancelButton", 10);
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("uiIsAdminUserChk")).SendKeys(Keys.Space);
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("uiCreateParticipantFormCancelButton")).Click();


            //Deal with Modal
            Utilities.WaitforElement(_driver, "modal-body", 10);
            Assert.Contains("Are you sure you wish to cancel? Any data you have entered will be lost.", _driver.PageSource);
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("uiConfirmationModalConfirmButton")).Click();

            Assert.Equal(Utilities.ManageWorkshopsURL, _driver.Url);  
  Debug.Write("need to write this text to output");
        }

    public void Dispose()
        {
            _driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error with `Console.WriteLine("08test1234");`? An error must be occuring just before `Console.WriteLine("08test1234");` and your program never reaches the line. Can you share your code trials?

Comment: Hi it passes the test it just doesn't write anything to the output. im putting it inside the test

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project and try `Console.WriteLine("08test1234");` and update me the status.

Comment: Hi Tried that and still nothing showing up. would it be easier to try write it to a txt file ?

Comment: Yes, that might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one I was using to do something similar. It just creates a text file with the data in it.

Add the local file path to your app config.

In this example I passed in the email and an account type. Then using the below I passed those values to a file so I could refer back to this later.

Then just call it in your code and pass the values.

```
        Call the method: MyPage.SignupEmail(email, acctType);

        Add to App.config: <add key="LocalFilePath" value="C:\\MyPath" />


        using System;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.IO;
        using TestFramework;


        namespace Tests
        {
            internal class SignupAccounts
            {
                public static void SignupEmail(string email, string acctType)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilePath"]))
                    {

                        Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilePath"]);
                    }
                    using (
                        StreamWriter writer =
                            File.AppendText(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFilePath"] + "\\file_{0}.txt",
                                Driver.GetCurrentTimestamp())))
                                //append a timestamp
                    {

                        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", "Applicant Email", @email));
                        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", "Applicant Acct Type", @acctType));
                        writer.WriteLine("Password: MyPass123");

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know how it goes. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not a console app, it won't write to the console. If it's a unit test, look for an Output link in the area where the results are displayed. I'm using Visual Studio and the output is displayed in the bottom left of the UI. If you click that link, it will open the results for the run which will display your text output. Having said that, I think it would be better to write things like this to a text file so that you can save the output, if needed. There are plenty of tutorials on how to write to a text file on the internet, I won't repeat those here.